# What are the elements of the group $6 \mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

I know that the group $\mathbb Z = \left\{ ..., -2,-1,0,1,2,... \right\}$, but what does the group $6 \mathbb Z$ represent?  I was thinking it might be $6 \mathbb Z = \left\{ \dots, -12, -6, 0, 6, 12,\dots\right\}$  but I am not familiar with this denotation.

Comment: You are correct. You could think of it as the ideal generated by 6 in $\mathbb{Z}$ if that helps?

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: I think generally the idea is not to delete questions, in case someone else asks in the future. If it's a duplicate, we mark it as such,

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'll just leave it then.

Answer (score 2):

The group $6\Bbb Z$ under addition is the set

$$\begin{align}
6\Bbb Z&:=\{ 6z\mid z\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&=\{0, \pm 6, \pm 12, \pm 18, \dots\} \\
&=\{\dots, -18, -12, -6, 0, 6, 12, 18, \dots\} \\
&=\{\text{all multiples, both positive and negative, of }6\}
\end{align}$$

under addition (since two multiples of $6$, say $6a$ and $6b$ for $a,b\in\Bbb Z$, add together to make $6(a+b)$, a multiple of six, as $a+b\in\Bbb Z$).